# No wireless networks visible with Acer Aspire VN7 (Atheros QCA6174)

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, atheros

I finally managed to install Ubuntu 15.10 on my new Acer Aspire VN7 (thanks to Rod Smith) but it seems to be a Ubuntu-unfriendly laptop...

Now I'm struggling with Wi-Fi, which doesn't want to work at all. After installation it simply didn't appear as activable (i.e. when clicking on the connection icon there was no "Enable Wi-Fi" option). After apt-get update & apt-get upgrade, the required drivers are installed, and the Enable Wi-Fi appears, but no wireless network is visible.

Furthermore, the boot process got slowed down dramatically, as the computer seems to wait a good 10 seconds trying to get the Wi-Fi work before giving up. I attach the dmesg log:

```
[   11.077913] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[   13.805517] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   13.805597] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   13.805600] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   14.077444] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   17.145948] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp8s0: link is not ready
[   17.163664] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: link down
[   17.163716] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp8s0: link is not ready
[   17.343363] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x10ecc0 0xffffffff (0x1f40822c)
[   22.396173] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable ani by default: -11
[   25.395742] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   26.681567] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 6 - 1
[   28.621844] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   28.621850] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   28.621854] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   33.674447] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   36.674058] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
```

and actually even while using the laptop the lines at 33 and 36 seconds repeat forever, every 10 seconds or so.

Any help or reference would be very appreciated. So far everything I've found boils down to downloading /ath10k/QCA6174/ from kernel.org github page, but after the upgrade these are already installed.

Another serious problem that I believe is linked is that, after a certain (random? I don't know) amount of time, the whole system just freezes completely, not accepting any command; only hard power off is possible. I think it may be linked to the above, though, since an older laptop of mine experienced similar complete freezes (albeit much more rarely) and the problem disappeared after activating the proprietary drivers (which are unfortunately unavailable for my network card...)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find a solution to my problem on the Ubuntu forums:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303541

The proposed solution is for an MSI GT72S 6QE, but the problems it displayed were exactly the same and installing the Git development driver at kvalo. Hopefully this will be introduced in a future upgrade of Ubuntu, but for now, it solved my problem like a charm! (well, kind of, had to reboot 4 times before it became effective, but after all the result is what matters...)

Comment: The solution from forum works for Acer Aspire V17 Nitro with Ubuntu 15.10. Thanks.